# Hash Sensibility for data changes

Tags: hash, language-agnostic

I've seen many hash algorithms has a common feature, it is any change in the data produce a total change in the hash code, although this is so, I would like to know if there is any known standard hash algorithm with a different behaviour, with little changes of hash for little changes of data, a kind of near-linear relation of amount of hash changes, respect to amount of data changes.

An idea for doing this is to create a hash concatenating various hashes calculated from parts of the data, it would use small partial hashes, or a bigger final hash, anyway, I would like to know if there is any algorithm having this behaviour.

Comment: Have you been able to find an implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like Simhash.  It's actually meant for finding "near duplicates".

e.g. http://irl.cs.tamu.edu/people/sadhan/papers/cikm2011.pdf